# Updated Ubuntu 16 to 18, doesn‘t boot properly - graphics troubles?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I updated and when it was done, there was this greyish screen. I used lots of tips from this site to get tis fixed but nothing worked. Finally I was able to boot the system using the command line and the `startx` command. now I'm logged in as "root" and can only open some apps. Firefox doesn't work, when I open the terminal it's a black box.

When I start the laptop it goes straight to command line, the. With startx most things don't work. How can I fix this?
I can't switch from root to another user because nothing opens when I click on it.

If you need any additional info let me know! I used Gnome on Ubuntu 16, if that's important (maybe this question shows how little I actually know about these things, so please use easy language ;) )

EDIT: the drive info says FAT (32-bit-version) is in /boot/efi but elsewhere it said I had the 64-bit-version of the update. I have gnome 3.28.2 installed.

EDIT: okay, the terminal isn‘t just a black box anymore and i finally see my desktop icons again, but other than that i can‘t really usw the laptop anymore. do i need to reinstall ubuntu? a friend will borrow her install cd, so at least i‘ll be aböe to do that, but i‘d rather not. any tips?

Answer (score -1):

From the way you mentioned everything it seems that your desktop environment is missing. Why don't you try to install it again using `sudo apt install unity`